# how to take full name from a file and compare it with what user search for?

Tags: c

so here i got a function that scan the file that has a single name and there phone number like that "andy 12345678"and when the user search for the name andy it will find it and printf the answer,now i want it to be more complex lets say the file has a full name and their number like this "andy bob mike 12345678" now when i use the code it will print "andy bob"because it fscan first two name "andy" and "bob"so how can i change the code that it can scan full name separately an compare it with what use searched for and print the full name with number
NOTE that the full name can be like that "andy bob"or "andy bob mike" or "andy"with there number

```
    void SearchPhoneBook()
{
    FILE *ph;
    ph = fopen("C:/Users/ec/Desktop/PhoneBook.txt", "r");
    printf("Enter the name you want to search for\n");


        char temp;
        char name[50];
        char Mobile[50];

        scanf("%c", &temp);
        char Search[20];
        scanf("%s", Search);






    while (fscanf(ph, "%s %s", name, Mobile) != EOF)
    {
            if (strcmp(name, Search) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s ", name);
                printf("%s", Mobile);
            }
    }


    MainMenu();
}
```

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input (keyboard or file).

Comment: ...and manually scan the line just read for the first digit. Anything before it is the name and the remainder is the number.

Comment: so i use fgets() for name and number,and then scan it in search function??i dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use a wildcard and stop scanning the `name` when some digit is found

```
char name[100];
char mobile[50];

fscanf(ph, "%99[^0123456789] %49s", name, mobile);
```

Comment: that wont work first im using fscanf() ot read what inside the file and it only reads the first character  in the file so if inside the file "andy bob 1234456"by your code it will only scan andy

Comment: Well, in your case you should use `fscanf(ph, "%99[^0123456789] %s", name, mobile)` and it will scan `andy bob` into `name` and  `1234456` into `mobile`

Comment: i tried it didnt work when i print the scan it only show "andy bob" without number as char mobile() took "bob" not number

Comment: It should work: http://cpp.sh/5stvs write _andy bob 1234456_ in the "Standard input" / "Text" section and run it

Comment: yeah it works thx,but now strcmp doesnt work as it cant compare "andy bob mike" with what user search for any suggestion for how i can overcome it lets say user want to search for "andy" i want code to get "andy bob mike" how can i do that as my code compare "andy" with "andy bob mike" so it consider it as different

Comment: Scan into the `Search` variable using `scanf("%19[^\n]", Search);` to fix that part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214577/discussion-between-crossplayer-and-david-ranieri).